# How can I add an AJAX-loaded form after the div that has been clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a list of items on a webpage. I would like to load a form via Ajax each time I click on any item in the list. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <... some html code for the first item ...>
</div>
</div class="item">
    <... some html code for the next item ...>
</div>
etc..
```

My goal is that if the user clicks on the first "item-div" a form shall be loaded using AJAX. The loaded form shall be inserted after the "item-div"... something like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <... some html code for the first item ...>
</div>
<form>
    <... some html code for the form... loaded via AJAX...>
</form>
</div class="item">
    <... some html code for the next item ...>
</div>
etc..
```

I can't understand why this won't work. Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".item").click(function(){
    $(this).after().load("loadform.php");
  });
});
```

The Ajax-load function overwrites the inner `<... some html code... >` instead of adding it after the "item-div". What is wrong? How can I solve it?

Comment: you can use jQuery insertAfter() Method, https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_insertafter.asp Or .append() method https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: I think it s not work @JordiJordi

Comment: You can not use load() with after() . When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched elements to the returned data.

Comment: @Jinesh maybe it s not work , nevermind i give this link with the diferent results because, the ajax load the results , then the problem is how it is inserted in the DOM. http://jsfiddle.net/designaroni/b33tL7hu/

Comment: @Gowire may I know where item-div is located?

Comment: @Jinesh: So, how can I combine load() with after()? That's my question... I want the loaded HTML-code to be added after my div that has been clicked

Comment: you can check my answer. you can use $.get or $.ajax for adding content in div.

Answer (score 1):

I have no dummy snippet somewhere in the internet where I can load some dummy content to simulate your `loadform.php` but I tested it locally and it is working.

1. First you attach click event, you can also use `on('click', function ...)`
2. You store the clicked element in `currentItem`
3. You do the Ajax request with `$.get`
4. If successful, append the Ajax request result to the stored element `currentItem`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".item").click(function(){
        var currentItem = $(this);
        $.get('loadform.php', function(data){
            currentItem.after(data); 
        }).fail(function() {
            console.log( "Can't load loadform.php" );
        })
    });
});
```

```css
.item {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    ... some html code for the first item ...
</div>
<div class="item">
    .. some html code for the next item ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Try the below way. Get the data from php and then insert it using after function.

```
$.get('loadform.php', function(data){ 
    $(this).after(data); 
  });
```

Comment: I have tried this. However it doesn't seem to work properly. In the Edge Console I can se an error "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined or null reference" (and a reference into jquery.min.js)
If I replace `$(this)` with `$(".item")` it will work (but the form is of course added after each item-divs. 
There seems to be some problems with using "this"...???

Answer (score 0):

You can not use load() with after() . When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched elements to the returned data.If you want to load content fro loadform you can try $.get method as below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".item").click(function(){
         $.get('loadform.php', function(data){ 
        $(this).after(data); 
       });

      });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks... But it seems that the use of $(this).after() doesn't work... but $(".item").after() seems to work... hmm

Comment: Can you accept my answer sir if it is useful to you.

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Answer (score 0):

Sometime it happens like, if you have inserted new html code into DOM with jquery, then you will follow this procedure. This will refresh the DOM behind the seen. It may help you, A simple test without ajax. You have error in your ajax request, first be sure to `console.log(data)` your return data, and then append it. Thanks.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
         <title>Smple Test</title>
        </head>
      <body>
       <div class="item">Div 1</div>
       <div class="item">Div 2</div>
       <div class="item">Div 3</div>
       <div class="item">Div 4</div>
     </body>
    </html>


    $(document).ready(function(){
      var form = '<form action="#" id="form1"><div>Hello Text</div></form>';
      $(document).on('click','.item',function(){
       $(this).after(form);
      });
    });
```

[A Simple JSFiddle Test](https://jsfiddle.net/g1an4zbq/20/)